# Run command in Symfony2

Tags: php

In the [Symfony 2 tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/page_creation.html) we are supposed to "run the following command":

```
php app/console init:bundle "Acme\StudyBundle" src
```

What they don't say is how to do it (where?)

Answer (score 1):

You should do this from the Symfony2 root directory (eg where you have 'app', 'src', 'vendor' and 'web') (if what you meant was "from which dir").

If you do not know how to execute this command, you have to type it in a terminal after using 'cd' to get to the right directory.

Comment: in web hosting service?

Comment: @noMAD:  Your hosting service must provide SSH access for you to be able to do this.  It would be much easier to run a server locally while you're developing your application.

Comment: You should not run these commands from a production website. As Patches suggested, run a local version and upload it to your hosting space when it's ready.

Comment: superuser.com may not be the best place to ask question regards sf2 and since there isn't yet any efficient way to receive support with symfony 2 I think the following proposal is a very good idea! - [A new Q&A site for symfony2](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36634/symfony2) - Please join & spread the word!